# How to know if an element is in an iframe or not?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe

**How to know if an element is in an iframe or not?**

I would like to learn how we can see if an element that we are searching is in an iframe or not. I could not find a submit button in a website until I saw a stackoverflow about it. They said that the submit button was in an iframe. When I look in the source code I can't see any iframe.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-submit" name="submitBtn">Créer un compte</button>
```

If you want to have a look at the website: *https://mail.protonmail.com/create/new?language=en*

Comment: open page souce HTML in browser (`Ctrl+U`) and search `iframe` (`Ctrl+F`). Evetually see HTML in `DevTools` in browser and there is also function to search some text in HTML.

Comment: BTW: if page uses JavaScript to add elements then you may have to wait until JavaScript add this element. You can try to use `time.sleep(seconds)` or Selenium has methods to wait for element. See [Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Comment: You can always use `driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')` to check if there are `iframes`

Comment: Yes the button is present inside an `iframe` There are two `iframes` on the page and button is present inside this iframe `//iframe[@title='Registration form' and @data-name='bottom']`

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can use `Ctrl+U` to see source HTML in browser and then you can use `Ctrl+F` to search any text ie. `iframe`. But `Ctrl+U` gives original HTML from server without elements added by JavaScript. But Mostly `iframe` is in original HTML and this method works.

But if page uses JavaScript to add even `iframe` then you may need `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` to see HTML with all added elements.

---

You can also use Selenium to check if there are `iframe` - ie.

```
driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
```

but if page uses JavaScript to add `iframe` then you may have to wait for new elements.

You can use primitive but easy to remember

```
time.sleep(seconds)
```

or `Selenium` has methods to check if elements is on page - see doc [Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).

Because it may raise error when it can't find element so it need `try/except` and code is longer.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

try:
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "iframe")))
except Exception as ex:
    #print(ex)
    print('len(all_iframes): 0')
```

**BTW:** It could use `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException` instead of `Exception` but it is harder to remember so I skip it here.

---

This code use `time.sleep()` to wait.

**BTW:** to switch to next `iframe` you have to first go back to main frame. Without switching it may search next `iframe` inside current `iframe`.

```
import selenium.webdriver
import time

url = 'https://mail.protonmail.com/create/new?language=en'

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(5) # JavaScript may need some time to add all elements

all_iframes = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
print('len(all_iframes):', len(all_iframes))

for number, frame in enumerate(all_iframes):
    print('--- frame:', number, '---')
    
    # switch to iframe
    driver.switch_to.frame(frame)

    # search buttons in iframe
    all_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('button')
    print('len(all_buttons):', len(all_buttons))
    
    # go back to main frame
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Result:

```
len(all_iframes): 2
--- frame: 0 ---
len(all_buttons): 0
--- frame: 1 ---
len(all_buttons): 1
```

---

**EDIT:**

Version with `WebDriverWait` but it needs to wait also for `buttons` because it doesn't wait full 5 seconds but at once when it find `iframes` it try to search `buttons` but JavaScript may need also time to add buttons in `iframe`

```
import selenium.webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
#import time

url = 'https://mail.protonmail.com/create/new?language=en'

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

#time.sleep(5) # JavaScript may need time to add all elements
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

try:
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "iframe")))
except Exception as ex:
    #print(ex)
    print('len(all_iframes): 0')

all_iframes = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
print('len(all_iframes):', len(all_iframes))

for number, frame in enumerate(all_iframes):
    print('--- frame:', number, '---')

    # switch to iframe
    driver.switch_to.frame(frame)

    try:
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "button")))
        
        all_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('button')
        print('len(all_buttons):', len(all_buttons))
    except Exception as ex:
        #print(ex)
        print('len(all_buttons): 0')
        
    # go back to main frame
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the button, if it's inside a frame it will show you frame options , Refer to this article-- https://www.guru99.com/handling-iframes-selenium.html

[image]